# How to query if Camera has Image plane.py

Tags: python, if-statement, runtime-error, maya

I am trying to figure out how to query if a camera has an image plane.
Right now i am using this code to find out what the name of the image plane is but, if **'persp'** doesn't have an image plane it errors out with:

```
line 2: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' #
```

if someone can help me understand how i can get it to check if the camera has an image plane before it errors out.

```
1: camShape = cmds.listRelatives('persp', type='camera', fullPath=True)[0]
2: ip = cmds.listConnections(camShape, type="imagePlane")[0]
3: ImageName = ip.split('>')[+1]
4: print ImageName`
```

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can check if there is any iplane then do the stuff or make empty list

```
camShape = cmds.listRelatives('persp', type='camera', fullPath=True)[0]
ip = cmds.listConnections(camShape, type="imagePlane") or []
if ip:
    ImageName = ip[0].split('>')[+1]
    print ImageName
```

Comment: Thanks... so simple I should have got that aha